# Maintain scroll position on page

Tags: asp.net, scroll

Hi there: I'm working on an ASP.NET app

I'm using MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback=true property but this doesn't seem to work with chrome. (works on IE),

Is there any other way to maintain scrool position without using this property?
tks

Answer (score 2):

check this may help you : http://joeoncode.com/post/MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack-2b-Safari-3d-Invalid-length-for-a-Base-64-char-array.aspx

```
<browsers>
    <browser refID="Safari1Plus">
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true" />
        </capabilities>
    </browser>
</browsers>
```

Put this file in your root directory or in the App_Browsers folder.

Comment: This works to me. The link is broken so here is another good one: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/207917/Maintain-Scroll-Position-Problem-fix-for-Chrome